# Graphql Authorization not send

Tags: authentication, testing, graphql, express-graphql

I have a graphql server, what is working with jwt auth.
The problem: The playground sometimes sends the Authorization header, sometimes not.
Not sends: on the AWS server.
Sends: Localy.
If im hitting the aws server with postman it also works, but the dev speed would be much better with working playground.
If You checks the Network tab, the Request Header should contain the Authorization token, but the is no Authorization entry, instead the token sent in Request Payload.

You can test it out: [a link](http://ec2-54-90-82-252.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5000/playground)